# k8s storage class issue when upgrade chart

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, prometheus, kubernetes-helm

We did an upgrade for our [kube-prom-stack](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack) helm chart and we are getting an error:

`cannot patch "vvc" with kind StorageClass: StorageClass.storage.k8s.io "vvc" is invalid: [parameters: Forbidden: updates to parameters are forbidden.`

we didnt change the storage class or something similar

this is the storage class

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
provisioner: pd.csi.storage.gke.io
parameters:
  type: pd-ssd
reclaimPolicy: Delete
allowVolumeExpansion: true
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

Any idea what we should do? any workaround/hint will be very helpful to us

Comment: can you provide more information  `kubectl describe sc [class-storage-name]`

Comment: Try using the command **$ kubectl replace -f storage-class.yaml --force**. If you still face the issue after trying the command can you "kubectl describe" your storage class?